# nth-child Expression To Select X and Up Elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I had some issues earlier today getting the css rule `nth-child` rule, and I finally figured it out.

I wanted to style a list so that every element past the Xth element would be styled.  I thought the formula would be complicated, ends up it was easier than I thought!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly simple to do.  You'll just need a selector like this:

`n+<ELEMENT_INDEX_PLUS_ONE>`

So, if you wanted to select every div after the third to have a red background...

`div:nth-child(n+4){ background-color: red; }`

Say you want the 10th list item and up to appear disabled...

`li:nth-child(n+10){ opacity: .4; }`

Hope that helps if you're looking to get a CSS selector that gets all elements after X number.